# Get current selected listview item from opened panel widget, jQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a dynamic listview where list items look similar to this:

```
<li data-item="Item X"><a href="#myPanelWidget">Item X</a></li>
```

So when clicking on an item, a panel will slide open. I can get to the data I want, but only the first item in the listview with this:

```
var item = $("myCollapsibleSet li").attr("data-item");
```

How can I get to the current selected item in the listview (the one that causes the panel to open).

Does jqm add a class or something to the one that is selected? jQuery Mobile 1.4.0.
Maybe like this:

```
var item = $("myCollapsibleSet li.current-selected").attr("data-item"); // ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the click event on each ListItem, get the item ID and then open the panel in code.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/T4nuN/)**

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li data-item="Item 1"><a href="#" class="itemPanel">Item 1</a></li>
    <li data-item="Item 2"><a href="#" class="itemPanel">Item 2</a></li>
    <li data-item="Item 3"><a href="#" class="itemPanel">Item 3</a></li>
    <li data-item="Item 4"><a href="#" class="itemPanel">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

In code, handle the click event on a class assigned to all the listitems (itemPanel in this example), get the data attribute from the parent LI and store it in a global variable, then open the panel:

```
var selectedItem = '';
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".itemPanel", function(){
        selectedItem = $(this).parents("li").data("item");
        $("#myPanelWidget").panel("open");    
    });

    $("#btnSelected").on("click", function(){
        alert(selectedItem);
    });
});
```

Comment: I had similar to this before, but it got slow and panel didn't move as smooth as I wanted: $("#myListview").on("click", "li", function() { 
     alert( $(this).attr("data-name") ); 
};

Comment: jQM does not to my knowledge automatically mark a listitem as selected, so you would still need to handle the click to unselect previous li and select clicked li: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/T4nuN/1/ Probably would not improve performance...